# add attribute to set when creating during upgrade script

Tags: setup

When creating an attribute inside an upgrade script (using class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`)

Is it possible to also assign the attribute to a specific attribute set only?

My code is:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'my_attribute', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'My Attribute',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'attribute_set' => 'My Attribute Set'
));
```

But the attribute only goes in default set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the attribute group:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'my_attribute', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'My Attribute',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'attribute_set' => 'My Attribute Set',
    'group' => 'Default' // <-- Change group if not default.
));
```

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module